# How to select nodes that don't have a parent node?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I would like to take a string like so:

```
<div>my div 1</div><p>para1</p><p>para2</p><p>para3</p><div>my div 2</div>
```

and then remove all `<p>` nodes.

I'm having difficulty with this because I think that the string above has no context, and JQuery needs a context to work with to allow selectors to work:

```
var p = "<div>my div 1</div><p>para1</p><p>para2</p><p>para3</p><div>my div 2</div>"
var pj = $(p)
```

When I run the statement below in FireBug, I get no elements returned.  Is this because the 'p' variable needs to be wrapped in another div for it to work?  I want to be able to strip the elements from the string, even though it is not part of the DOM.

```
$("p",pj)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to search elements at the same level, like this:

```
$(pj).filter("p");
```

`$("p",pj)` translates to `$(pj).find("p")` under the covers, that's why it's not finding anything, because the `<p>` elements are descendants of `pj`, they're members.  To be clear, jQuery doesn't need them to be contained in anything, it's a descendant vs non-descendant issue.

---

The alternative approach is to add them to a temporary fragment and always use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/), like this:

```
var p = "<div>my div 1</div><p>para1</p><p>para2</p><p>para3</p><div>my div 2</div>"
var pj = $('<div />').html(p);
```

Then `$("p",pj)` would work.

Comment: Great, thats exactly what I was after. The filter option didn't work because I wanted to select everything but the tag in question, unless you know how to negate the filter?
In fact what I wanted was to strip out script tags from an html string.

In the end I think I used the 2nd line of your option 2 to accomplish this:

var safeText = $("<div />").html(editorText).html();

Does this look right to you?

Comment: @Jon - if you wanted the stripped version it'd look like: `var filteredHTML = $("<div />").html(editorText).find('p').remove().end().html();`

Comment: Actually .html() strips <script> tags out so I don't need the filter method, I can use .html(string).html() to do the trick on the div fragment. I've learnt something anyway! Thanks again